# how can I style ckeditor5?( background-color and stuff )

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, ckeditor5

I've been trying to give background-color to ckeditor but nothing seems to work.

looked at the class names in browser inspect and tried to write style relative to those classes, but it didn't work. I think it overrides them.

can anyone help me out?

Comment: Try using `!important` like
`font-size: 19px !important`

Comment: Also try removing the `scoped` if you have it in `<style scoped>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background colour of the ckeditor5 window is defined using a CSS variable like this:

```
.ck.ck-editor__main>.ck-editor__editable {
    background: var(--ck-color-base-background);
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

You can customise the appearance but importing a new CSS file that overwrites these variables. They provide a good guide here:
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/ui/theme-customization.html

Comment: found what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the styles you wrote were loaded properly, you should see them in the dev tools with a strikethrough if they're not applied
2. increase the specificity of the styles, either by giving them a parent so it'd be `.parent .class {}` or if that's not enough to override the class of CKEditor you can keep increasing the specificity or adding `!important`, I prefer not using important unless if I must, because you may want to override the override later.